# How to use (Teigha.NET) load dwg flle from byte[]?

Tags: c#

I use Teigha.NET dll read dwg file, it has two method, I know how to use method (1), but now I download file from ftp and get result is byte[], so I want to use method(2), who can tell me how to use method(2)?

1. `public void ReadDwgFile(string fileName,FileShare fileSharing, bool allowCPConversion,string password)`
2. `public void ReadDwgFile(IntPtr drawingFile,bool allowCPConversion, string password)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the second method, according to its parameter name, is looking for a file handle too, meaning Teigha.NET (which I'm unfamiliar with) expects you to provide it with an existing file.
So you first want to save you byte array into a file, then load it with Teigha.NET.

To store a `byte[]` to a file, do the following:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
```